# 2005 chev aveo brake fluid reservoir

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, aveo

My 2005 Chevrolet Aveo brake fluid reservoir is empty once in a while and a few hours later, it is full again. What is the problem? I changed the brakes and had clean fluid put back in. It is empty once and then full later.

Comment: Did you bleed the brakes properly when changing the fluid?

Comment: Any chance you are looking at the fluid level sometimes with the hand brake on and sometimes with the hand brake off?